# Ruby get and set in one method

Tags: ruby, getter-setter

I'm wondering what's the canonical way in Ruby to create custom setter and getter methods. Normally, I'd do this via `attr_accessor` but I'm in the context of creating a DSL. In a DSL, setters are called like this (using the `=` sign will create local variables):

```
work do
 duration 15
 priority 5
end
```

Therefore, they must be implemented like this:

```
def duration(dur)
 @duration = dur
end
```

However this makes implementing a getter a bit tricky: creating a method with the same name but with no arguments will just overwrite the setter.

So I wrote custom methods that do both the setting and the getting:

```
def duration(dur=nil)
 return @duration = dur if dur
 return @duration if @duration
 raise AttributeNotDefinedException, "Attribute '#{__method__}' hasn't been set"
end
```

Is this a good way to go about it? Here's a gist with test cases:

[Ruby Custom Getters & Setters](https://gist.github.com/3033911)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trickier case is if you want to set duration to nil. I can think of two ways of doing this

```
def duration(*args)
  @duration = args.first unless args.empty?
  @duration
end
```

Allow people to pass any number of args and decide what to do based on the number. You could also raise an exception if more than one argument is passed.

Another way is

```
def duration(value = (getter=true;nil))
  @duration = value unless getter
  @duration
end
```

This exploits default arguments a little: they can be pretty much any expression.

When called with no arguments `getter` is set to true, but when an argument is supplied (even if it is nil) the default value is not evaluated. Because of how local variable scope works `getter` ends up nil.

Possibly a little *too* clever, but the method body itself is cleaner.

Comment: This might be "clever", but it is a fairly well-known idiom, so I would certainly let it slide in a code review.

Comment: Thanks, these are great ideas. I don't have a use case for setting a value to nil, but it's good to know how to cover it, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

For something like this, I prefer to separate the underlying class from the DSL. That is, make a Work class that has the usual accessors, `duration` and `duration=`. And to use that class via a DSL, wrap the work instance with something that can invoke the accessors situationally, like this:

```
class AccessorMultiplexer

  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args)
    method = "#{method}=" unless args.empty?
    @target.send method, *args
  end

end
```

Wherever you want to use your Work class via a DSL, you'd wrap it with `AccessorMultiplexer.new(work)`.

If you're opposed to metaprogramming in the wrapper, you could always make a specific WorkDSL wrapper that does the same without using `method_missing`. But it would maintain the separation and keep your Work class from being polluted by the quirks of the DSL syntax. You may want to use the Work class somewhere else in your code where the DSL would be in the way. In rake or a script or -- who knows.

(Adapted from my answer on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9023/method-naming-and-violating-single-responsibility/9045#9045).)

Comment: I like the idea of separation, so I'll pursue these ideas. But what would you use instead of `method_missing` in a WorkDSL wrapper? I'd rather not use that method - seems too 'catch-all' for this situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That seems fine to me, although it seems strange that you raise an error if the value hasn't been set. This is what I would normally do:

```
def duration(dur=nil)
 @duration = dur if dur
 @duration
end
```

However this is a simplistic approach because it means you can't set `@duration` back to `nil` using just this method

Comment: Not an error (that would be too drastic) but an exception, ie the input is not illegal but false. The reason I prefer raising an exception to returning nil is that it doesn't propagate to the caller and is discovered instantly, as opposed to when a method is called on nil. [Watch this screencast](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/how-and-why-to-avoid-nil)

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this

```
def duration dur='UNDEFINED'
  @duration = dur if dur != 'UNDEFINED'
  @duration
end
```

You can replace UNDEFINED with your favorite thing